# Flow Chart with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

I have some trouble with the last block closing the block chart. In practice, with the following setting, the result is that the "end" is attached to the previous one and I cannot understand hot to make a vertical space. Alos I would like to set the same dimensions (height and width) for each block.

```
\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
decision/.style = {draw, diamond, aspect=1.5}
tmp/.style  = {coordinate}, 
sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style = {coordinate},
output/.style= {coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']

\node[sum] (start) {start};
\node[block, below of =start] (A) {solution};
\node[block, below of=A] (B) {solution};
\node[block, below of=B] (C) {calculation};
\node[block, below of=C] (D) {Updating geometry};
\node[sum,   below of=D] (end) {end};

\draw [->] (start) -- node{$\bold{v}, p,\bold{u}, q$} (A);
\draw [->] (A) -- node{$\bold{v}, p$} (B);
\draw [->] (B) -- node{$\bold{u}, q$} (C);
\draw [->] (C) -- node{$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta}$} (D);
\draw [->] (D) -- node{} (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Can you make your code compilable, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a deprecated way of node positioning. (You also had a `node distance` in the definition of `sum`.) With the `positioning` library, you can solve the problems. The syntax changes from `below of=...` to `below=of ...` or `below=<distance> of ...`. The equal sizes can be achieved with the `eqparbox` package, and you need to compile twice. I added an `equal size` style, which takes an optional argument that indicates the group of nodes that you want to make equal, below the boxes and circles are taken to be these groups.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\newbox\eqnodebox
\begin{document}
\tikzset{equal size/.style={execute at begin
    node={\setbox\eqnodebox=\hbox\bgroup},
    execute at end node={\egroup\eqmakebox[#1][c]{\copy\eqnodebox}}},
    equal size/.default=A,
    block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum
    width=3em,equal size=B},
    sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle,equal size=S},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2.5em,>=latex']

\node[sum] (start) {start};
\node[block, below=of start] (A) {solution};
\node[block, below=of A] (B) {solution};
\node[block, below=of B] (C) {calculation};
\node[block, below=of C] (D) {Updating geometry};
\node[sum,   below=of D] (end) {end};

\draw [->] (start) -- node{$\boldsymbol{v}, p,\boldsymbol{u}, q$} (A);
\draw [->] (A) -- node{$\boldsymbol{v}, p$} (B);
\draw [->] (B) -- node{$\boldsymbol{u}, q$} (C);
\draw [->] (C) -- node{$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta}$} (D);
\draw [->] (D) -- node{} (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `arrows` library is also somewhat deprecated, but I kept it for the moment, and I had to replace `\bold`, which I do not know, by `\boldsymbol`. For these reasons it is always better to present compilable code, as you were asked to in the comments.

**ADDENDUM**: You may use `chains` to put the nodes on a chain. I added a style that allows you to add an edge label.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,chains}
\newbox\eqnodebox
\makeatletter
\tikzset{ce/.code=\gdef\tikz@chain@edge@label{#1},ce={},
labeled join/.style={every join/.append style={#1,
edge label={\tikz@chain@edge@label}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikzset{equal size/.style={execute at begin
    node={\setbox\eqnodebox=\hbox\bgroup},
    execute at end node={\egroup\eqmakebox[#1][c]{\copy\eqnodebox}}},
    equal size/.default=A,
    block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum
    width=3em,equal size=B,on chain,join},
    sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle,equal size=S,on chain,join},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ node distance=2.5em,>=latex']
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below,labeled join={->}]
\node[sum,ce=A] (start) {start};
\node[block,ce={$\boldsymbol{v}, p,\boldsymbol{u}, q$}] (A) {solution};
\node[block,ce={$\boldsymbol{v}, p$}] (B) {solution};
\node[block,ce={$\boldsymbol{u}, q$}] (C) {calculation};
\node[block,ce={$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta}$}] (D) {Updating geometry};
\node[sum,ce={}] (end) {end};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note also that you may want to look at the `forest` package, which may provide you more convenient ways of creating this figure.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum
    width=3em,text width={width("updating geometry")},text centered},
    sum/.style= {draw, fill=white, circle},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={el/.style={edge label={node[midway,circle,right]{#1}}},
    edge={-latex'},where n children=0{sum}{if level=0{sum}{block}},
    l sep=2.5em}
[start
 [solution,el={$\boldsymbol{v}, p,\boldsymbol{u}, q$}
  [solution,el={$\boldsymbol{v}, p$}
   [calculating,el={$\boldsymbol{u}, q$}
    [updating geometry,el={$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta}$}
     [end]
    ]   
   ]
  ]
 ] 
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you cat, I will try to use an alternative to arrow library. Just one last question: do you know how to loop over the same block also?

Comment: @FlyBob What do you mean by "loop over the same block"? There is the chains library, which helps you to automatize drawing such chains. I could add an example if that's what you're asking. (BTW, the `arrows` library is not too deprecated, just superseded by `arrows.meta`, but if you are OK with the arrow, this is fine.)

Comment: Ok I understand so I will mantain it in this case. Yes, if you can add an example it would be great. Just to be more specific, I would like to have an arrow that goes out from one block and returns to the same block.